# Extract email addresses from Outlook Like

Tags: email, outlook

I run a book store and often use email to commuticate with customers. I opened a HotMail account back in the 90s and have received over 100,000 emails. I'm about to retire and would like to send an email to all previous customers to thank them for their business and inform them the store is closing. How can I get a list of email addresses for everyone who has emailed me?

I know a little bit of Python, in case there isn't a tool to do it. I have POP and IMAP access to the mail box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step by step guidance for your reference: [How To Extract Email Addresses From Mail Folders In Outlook?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1449-outlook-extract-contacts.html)

Answer (score 2):

You should **not** do that. Even though you had a business relationship with them, it may not be the case at the moment anymore. What you are trying to do is what I would call spamming. It may be in good faith, but it isn't good practice.

You have to know that 20+ years old addresses are not there anymore. Businesses close, merge, reorganize. Peoples in that companies retired, changed company or quit. What you will end with is a bag of nonsense addresses. I would guess that the success rate of your mailing is under 30%.

I highly recommend to resist of any attempt to actually mail them. In the worst case you would also be stopped by Microsoft after sending only a fraction of your mails due to sending limitations and restrictions.